# Quick Questions about series (again)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have some questions again, it's a bit different this time.

There is a series $a_n > 0 \forall \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sqrt{a_n+1}-1)$ converge?

*My answer:* no. Because $\lim_{n \to \infty}=0$ because $a_n$ converges. However, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{a_n + 1} -1=-1$. By the divergence test it automatically diverges.

There are two series, $a_n, b_n > 0$ for all $n \in$ natural numbers, where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_n b_n}=1$, then does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges.

*My answer*: I think this is a clear yes. Limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ by definition since $a_n$ converges, but $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_n b_n}=1$, so that means $a_n$ must be the inverse of $b_n$...so by this fact we know that $\sum b_n$ diverges.

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$ then $\sqrt{a_n + 1} -1 \to 0$, not to $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{a_{n}+1}-1=\dfrac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{a_{n}+1}+1}\leq a_{n},
\end{align*}
so $\sum(\sqrt{a_{n}+1}-1)$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$b_n := \sqrt{a_n + 1} - 1 = \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n + 1} + 1}$$
Note that
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \color{blue}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}\cdot \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{a_{n} + 1} + 1}{\sqrt{a_{n+1} + 1} + 1}}\to\color{blue}\alpha \cdot \color{red}1$$
Now, since $\sum a_n$ converges, we have $\alpha < 1$, and therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} < 1$$
This implies that $\sum b_n$ converges as well.